# How to print the second column of many files?

Tags: awk, paste

I have more than 10 files, the 1st column is the same in all files, I need to collect all the columns 2 in all files against the 1st column in one file.
I tried with **paste** then **awk** but this print only the columns in the first 10 files

```
paste p{01..20}.dat | awk '{print $1" "$2" "$4" "$6" "$8" "$10" "$12" "$14" "$16"  "$18" "$20}' > output.dat
```

example for p01.dat file

```
0.000 1.3594
0.500 1.3600
1.000 1.3603
1.500 1.3601
2.000 1.3595
2.500 1.3584
3.000 1.3570
3.500 1.3552
4.000 1.3530
4.500 1.3506
```

all other files have the same format and the same 1st column

Comment: can you post the actual testable input example?

Comment: see the updates

Comment: what does mean your *collect all the columns 2 in all files against the 1st column* - group all values from the 2nd field by the value of the 1st field? Post the expected output for your `p01.dat`

Comment: the 1st column does not change from file to file, so I want to print the first column from one file then all columns 2 from all files to generate only one output file.

Answer (score 4):

Just a variant of @John1024's solution:

```
paste -d '=' p*.dat | sed 's/=\S*//g'
```

Comment: intelligent solution

Comment: Quite nicely done.

Comment: MohsenEl-Tahawy and @John1024, thank you (it was a bit of luck).

Answer (score 3):

You need a `for` loop.  Try:

```
paste p{01..20}.dat | awk '{printf "%s",$1; for (i=2;i<=NF;i=i+2) printf " %s",$i; print ""}'
```

#### Example

Let's take three input files:

```
$ paste p*.dat
1 a     1 aa    1 aaa
2 b     2 bb    2 bbb
3 c     3 cc    3 ccc
```

Our command generates:

```
$ paste p*.dat | awk '{printf "%s",$1; for (i=2;i<=NF;i=i+2) printf " %s",$i; print ""}'
1 a aa aaa a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
2 b bb bbb b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b
3 c cc ccc c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c
```

#### Example using 20 files

We'll start with the three files above and create 17 more:

```
for i in {04..20}; do cp p01.dat p$i.dat; done
```

We can verify that paste works:

```
$ paste p{01..20}.dat
1 a     1 aa    1 aaa   1 a     1 a     1 a     1 a     1 a     1 a     1 a     1 a     1 a     1 a     1 a     1 a     1 a     1 a     1 a     1 a     1 a
2 b     2 bb    2 bbb   2 b     2 b     2 b     2 b     2 b     2 b     2 b     2 b     2 b     2 b     2 b     2 b     2 b     2 b     2 b     2 b     2 b
3 c     3 cc    3 ccc   3 c     3 c     3 c     3 c     3 c     3 c     3 c     3 c     3 c     3 c     3 c     3 c     3 c     3 c     3 c     3 c     3 c
```

We can also verify that the awk command works:

```
$ paste p{01..20}.dat | awk '{printf "%s",$1; for (i=2;i<=NF;i=i+2) printf " %s",$i; print ""}'
1 a aa aaa a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
2 b bb bbb b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b
3 c cc ccc c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c
```

Comment: this still gives the same problem since  **paste p*.dat** print only the columns in the first 10 files so the command after **|** will works only on the first 10 files

Comment: @MohsenEl-Tahawy As the updated answer shows, I cannot reproduce that problem: `paste` works fine on 20 files.  Can you try it again and, if it is still not working, provide more details?

Comment: sorry, it was my bad, actually, I was trying to print 11 files but I discovered that one of the files is empty so I thought it prints only 10 files. now why the first column appears as **s** and not as **1 2 3**

Comment: Very good.  Also, the `s` was due to a typo: I had `"s"` where I needed `"%s"`.  Answer updated with corrected code.

Answer (score 2):

**`paste`** + **`cut`** + **`seq`** trick:

```
paste -d' ' p{01..20}.dat | cut -d' ' -f1,"$(seq -s',' 2 2 20)"
```

---

Test case (on 3 files):

```
$ head p0[1-3].dat
==> p01.dat <==
0.000 1.3594
0.500 1.3600
1.000 1.3603
1.500 1.3601
2.000 1.3595
2.500 1.3584
3.000 1.3570
3.500 1.3552
4.000 1.3530
4.500 1.3506

==> p02.dat <==
0.000 2.3594
0.500 2.3600
1.000 2.3603
1.500 2.3601
2.000 2.3595
2.500 2.3584
3.000 2.3570
3.500 2.3552
4.000 2.3530
4.500 2.3506

==> p03.dat <==
0.000 3.3594
0.500 3.3600
1.000 3.3603
1.500 3.3601
2.000 3.3595
2.500 3.3584
3.000 3.3570
3.500 3.3552
4.000 3.3530
4.500 3.3506
```

---

```
paste -d' ' p{01..03}.dat | cut -d' ' -f1,"$(seq -s',' 2 2 6)"
0.000 1.3594 2.3594 3.3594
0.500 1.3600 2.3600 3.3600
1.000 1.3603 2.3603 3.3603
1.500 1.3601 2.3601 3.3601
2.000 1.3595 2.3595 3.3595
2.500 1.3584 2.3584 3.3584
3.000 1.3570 2.3570 3.3570
3.500 1.3552 2.3552 3.3552
4.000 1.3530 2.3530 3.3530
4.500 1.3506 2.3506 3.3506
```